# How to change the date format from datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a variable to select future dates in a calendar but I can't change the format of the date.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().date()
diff = datetime.timedelta(days=3)
bDate = now + diff
bDate.strftime("%d %m %Y")
print(bDate)
```

I expected the date to come out as DD-MM-YYYY but it comes out 2019-08-04

Any ideas on how to change to DD-MM-YYYY?

Comment: Because [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) returns a new string, it *doesn't* change the value of `bDate`. `print(bDate.strftime(...))`.

Answer (score -1):

use below one

```
datetime.date.strftime(bDate, "%m-%d-%Y")
```

output:

```
08-04-2019
```

Comment: Why call that on (a different) class? It's an instance method!